# WCF Async only operation

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous

I have a client that use both async and sync method from a WCF service.

I don't see any good reason to keep some sync call. Since I can with Task call async method within a sync one.

And it's better to not block UI when I call my service.

So I'm currently trying to remove every sync call.
First is it a good pratice in WCF? If not why?

And second I use svcutils to generate my files. I have both sync and async call.

The project is big and to remove sync call the easiest way is to generate only async call with svcutils. 
So with compile error I will be able to only keep async easily.

But I can't find any option on svcutils that disable the sync method generation.

Any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

In case if it is UI application it is better to use only async methods, as you said - to not block UI during calls.

Regarding svcutil.exe, it can't create only async methods and ignore sync's.
You can use /async parameter, but it will create all as async, which does not work for you. Means, better to delete synchronous methods manually first.